# ARM embedded Linux toolchain

Tags: linux, arm

a simple question regarding Arm and Linux:

I just built the arm-none-eabi toolchain on my Ubuntu to compile the linux kernel for ARM. Is this toolchain also capable of compiling binaries to be executed within the linux environment running on my ARM or do I need a second toolchain?

ah, a second question comes to my mind. the toolchain one can create with buildroot; is it used to compile Linux for ARM or to compile binaries for a Linux system running on ARM?

can anyone explain this a little bit more detailed to me?!

Comment: Is your question about the difference between a cross-compiler and a straight compiler ?

Comment: nope, the question is about the toolchain one uses to build linux for ARM and the toolchain one uses to build applications which should run on the embedded Linux. Or is there no need to have 2 different toolchain and one can use one toolchain for theses named use cases? I read that it matters if the toolchain is build with newlib or µClibc depending on what your purpose is.

Comment: The same cross-toolchain should be able to compile the Linux kernel and your embedded applications (in C or C++ at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have toolchain in place, you can compile any program for Linux/ARM enviroment. You only need that one toolchain. I dont see any difference between Linux and any other program.

Comment: you think so? well I read that a toolchain that uses newlib is not meant for Linux systems. For this purpose one should use µClibc instead...

Comment: Well im no expert on the subject, but your toolchain should use the same c library that will be deployed on the ARM/Linux device. You making the whole system yourself or using a Linux distribution?

Comment: I am going to build a Linux on my own meant to run on an ARM device.

Comment: Well then it depends which libc you will install on that device. That lib should be the lib used by your toolchain to build programs. Although some are compatible i wouldnt count on it. Also libc which was used to build the kernel shouldnt matter. You should be able to use any user space libc you wish

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer the question with a question.  the gcc or gnu compiler that you can use to compile a kernel for the computer you are running linux on now.  Can you use that same compiler for compiling application programs that run on this computer or do you need a second gcc compiler for applications?

If it can build the linux kernel and that kernel happens to work then it most likely can build applications that can work on that kernel.  I am sure there are exceptions that people can come up with.  But in practice, specifically arm-none-linux-eabi, we use it every day to build a working linux system for arm and to compile the programs that run on that arm linux system.  Same compiler/toolchain.

Comment: ok but I am using arm-none-eabi-gcc not arm-none-linux-eabi. and as said above, I read that newlib, which I used to build arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain, is not meant for OS. Instead one should use µClibc. Am I totally wrong here?

Comment: are you able to build linux with it?  If so I would assume you could and would need to build the linux apps with the same tool.  what happens when you tried to do all of these things, did it work or fail?  Why not use arm-none-linux-eabi?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible! I have created an Ubuntu environment with an arm-2011.09 cross compiler toolchain and from this environment routinely build both Arm applications and the linux kernel components needed for Buildroot. All work great!

I build these environments using Docker which makes the development environment very portable between work, home, and elsewhere. If Docker is around I'm in business.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Tom Toms it certainly does answer the first of his two questions. He asked if the toolchain used to compile the linux kernel could also compile other programs for running in his arm environment.  As I stated I do, therefore he can.

Comment: Yeah read that one a bit fast sorry. You should definitely rephrase it a little (ie: Yes it is possible. I have created [...]) to make it clear.